# MapBox using dynamic data points

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I'm using MapBox to show several store locations on a page. My specific use case is a little complex for what I am initially seeing tutorials for on the Mapbox site.

I have a few pages, one page for each city. Each city page should have it's own map with different location points. (This is in React, so each city page is a template component using WP data).

Is there a way to either bring in data from an outside source (like WP) or use data from a json file in the React project? i haven't been able to find any information on how to do this so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most definitely a way to bring in data from an outside source or JSON file. I wrote a comprehensive guide, "A Complete Guide to Sources and Layers in React and Mapbox GL JS", that details how you can add different types of data to a Mapbox Map using React. You can find the guide [here](https://www.lostcreekdesigns.co/writing/a-complete-guide-to-sources-and-layers-in-react-and-mapbox-gl-js).

I also put together a Code Sandbox to accompany the guide which you can find [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mapbox-sources-and-layers-y0jsl?file=/src/App.js). The guide and code sandbox detail how to add spatial data from various sources (Mapbox hosted data, from a JSON file, from an API) and then how to display it as a layer. I figured it is easier to just link to both instead of writing a really long post here.

Hope this helps! I am also in the process of writing a comprehensive playbook for working with React and Mapbox in case you are interested! You can view it [here](https://gumroad.com/l/mapbox-handbook).

Comment: wow thanks! i'll take a look. i really appreciate it